# How to execute background task when Android app is closed / set to background?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, background-process, android-lifecycle

My Android 4+ app is connected to a custom web service that is used to sync data every few minutes. To make sure, that the online data is always up to date, I want to trigger the sync when ever the app is closed / send to background.

Under iOS this is quite easy:

- Listen to `applicationDidEnterBackground:` in the AppDelegate
- Use `beginBackgroundTaskWithName:` to start you long running background task and to avoid being suspended while the task is still running

**How to do this on Android?**

**First problem** is, that there is nothing equivalent to `applicationDidEnterBackground:`. All solution I found so far propose to use the main Activities `onPause()` method. However this called any time the main `Activity` is paused, which is also the case when another `Activity` is started within the app. The is true for the `onActivityPaused()` method from `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` interface.

So, how to detect that the **app** (not just an `Activity`) is closed or send to the background?

**Second problem** is, that I did not find any information on how to run background task. All solutions point to simply start an `AsyncTask`, but is this really the correct solution?

`AsyncTask` will start a new task, but will this task also run, when the app is closed/inactive? What do I have to do, to prevent the app and the task from being suspended after a few seconds? How can I make sure, that the task can complete, before the app is completely suspended?

Comment: you can use services for that

Comment: Have you considered a service?

Comment: Use a service https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: Thank you for the hint about the Services. I will check this out.

Why the downvote? If there is something wrong with the question, please let me know so that I can improve it. A downvote without any comment is not very helpful.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The following code will help you to post your contents when your app is closed or in the background:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SendDataService extends Service {
    private final LocalBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    protected Handler handler;
    protected Toast mToast;
 
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public SendDataService getService() {
            return SendDataService .this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() { 

// write your code to post content on server
            }
        });
        return android.app.Service.START_STICKY;
    }

}
```

More explanation of my code is:

Service runs in the background even if your application is in the background, but remember, it always runs on the main thread, because of which I created a separate thread to perform your background operations.

Service is started as a sticky one, as even if because of any reason your service got destroyed in the background it will automatically get restarted.

More details can be found here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

And to check if your app is in the foreground/background, the following code will help:

```
  private boolean isAppOnForeground(Context context) {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    if (appProcesses == null) {
      return false;
    }
    final String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    for (RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {
      if (appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND && appProcess.processName.equals(packageName)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}

// Use like this:
boolean foregroud = new ForegroundCheckTask().execute(context).get();
```

Happy Coding!!!!

Comment: you have used handler to do background work, after how much time will the handler get invoked for repeated network calls?

Comment: Thank you very much. A `Service` seems indeed to be a perfect solution for Problem Nr. 2. What about the first problem: How to properly detect that the app was paused/closed and not just an Activity?

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer is not correct.

Unfortunately, the author believes that posting a new `Runnable` task to the `Handler()` creates a separate thread - *"I created a separate thread to perform your background operations"* :

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() { 
           // write your code to post content on server
        }
    });
    return android.app.Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

`onStartCommand()` callback is always called on the main thread, and the new `Handler()` is attached to the current thread (which is "main"). So the `Runnable` task is posted at the end of main thread queue.

To fix the issue and execute the `Runnable` in a really separate thread you can use `AsyncTask` as the simplest solution:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // ...
        }
    });
    return android.app.Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

Think yourself before you copy-paste anything ...

Comment: I think new Handler() creates a new thread or some default thread, but I assure you that the code running in new Handler() is not running on main thread. As I always get exception whenever I do ui work in new Handler runnable.

Answer (score 4):

You can use services for what you want to achieve. A service will **keep on running in the background even when the activity component has been destroyed**, provided you have not invoked stopService(..) or stopSelf() methods.

In the service you can make an Async network call, preferably using retrofit, and then you can update you local storage like Sqlite DB with the latest data fetched from your web service.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) is the official link, you can just use an unbounded service for what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you very much. A `Service` seems indeed to be a perfect solution for Problem Nr. 2. What about the first problem: How to properly detect that the app was paused/closed and not just an Activity?

Comment: For that you can override activity life cycle methods like onPause() and onDestroy(). If your activity is the last item in the back stack and you press the android default back button, then onDestroy() gets called, and you exit from your app.

Answer (score -2):

For background operations, you can use `WorkManager`.