# Volley TimeoutError when app asleep

Tags: android, android-volley, android-internet

I implemented a Volley Request interval to fire a request periodically:

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    final int interval = 3000;

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            // Volley request here...
            Volleyclient client = Volleyclient.getInstance();
            client.doSomeVolleyRequest(MainActivity.this, someListener, someDataToSend);

            handler.postDelayed(this, interval);
        }
    }, interval);
```

It works fine as long as the app is in foreground. If i push the home Button and the app goes asleep i got a Volley TimeoutError and I cannot figure out why. Same behaviour if i switch to "standby" mode (screen off). As soon as i toggle my app back to foreground it continues the volley requests.

I suspect it isnt really a timeout but an internet connection permission issue while falling asleep. I use the following permisions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Is anybody out there who is able to explain the reason for that behaviour?
It would be nice if you can show me a workaround to make my app continue sending requests whenever the app is running.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with your thread. postDelayed operations in going queue in UI threads. When the phone going sleep there is no UI thread for working. I assume to changing thread will solve this problem. Let me know if not works.

**Edit:** You said your codes in your activity. But when the phone locked(or black screen) all activities going pause state. If want keep working while phone sleeping you have to use **service**. Services has no lifecycle like activities. They will attached to phone and keep working(even your application has killed) until you make them stop or user interrupt.

There is a example which explains well: [How to execute background task when Android app is closed / set to background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39507506/how-to-execute-background-task-when-android-app-is-closed-set-to-background)

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. The code is currently placed directly in the onCreate-Method of my MainActivity. Can you point me to a simple solution to put it into another thread by posting a link or a little bit of sample code?

Comment: I migrated everything into a service now. Nearly the same behaviour on real device. If I am connected via USB (debugging) it continues sending if app is not in foreground. If i disconnect the USB it gives me a Volley TimeoutError when not in foreground. In all cases sending failes in sleep mode (display off). Everything works fine if i put the app back to foreground. Very strange and anoying.

Comment: It seems to be the case that the service itself is working fine in background. An Error-Toast ist shown periodically when running in background in all cases so the thread seems to run. Just the volley communication fails.

Comment: Ok, I got it: The reason was the doze mode. Thank you for your advice any way. But the thread wasnt the problem.

Comment: Great! Happy the hear that! Can you update your question by adding how to solve.

Answer (score 2):

After a long time of research I am able to answer my own question now.
I hate it but nobody else was able to figure it out.

The simple reason for the descripted behaviour is: The doze mode!

It was not a threading issue it simply was a disabled network access caused by falling into doze mode. One feature of the doze mode is: Network access is suspended.

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/diving-into-doze-mode-for-developers/