# IntentService or JobScheduler to perform I/O intensive data save operation during onPause

Tags: android, multithreading, intentservice, android-intentservice, android-jobscheduler

Currently, during Activity `onPause()`, I'm performing I/O operations, to persist application data into disk.

```
private void save() {
    saveDataToFiles();
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    save()
}
```

As time goes on, the application requirement becomes complex. Not only I need to save the data to files. I also need to perform several additional tasks.

- Save data to SQLite
- Save data over the network

Hence, the code will evolve into

```
private void save() {
    saveDataToFiles();
    saveDataToSQLite();
    saveDataOverTheInternet();
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    save()
}
```

Now, `save()` method is a pretty time-consuming method. It is not a good idea to perform time-consuming operation in UI thread.

I went through [How to execute background task when Android app is closed / set to background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39507506/how-to-execute-background-task-when-android-app-is-closed-set-to-background) (It is dated 2016. So, some advices might no longer valid.)

My initial plan is move `save()` method to be executed by `IntentService`

I don't plan to use `Service`. As you can see 2 **Hello...** examples in https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html , `extends Service` with own threading mechanism is much more complex than `extends IntentService`

However, I also notice some warning from Google https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

> Note: If your app targets Android 5.0 (API level 21) or later, it's
>   recommended that you use the JobScheduler to execute background
>   services.

I'm targeting API 25. So, I should take that advice seriously.

### My questions are

1. Should I use `JobScheduler` or `IntentService` during `onPause()`? I estimate the execution time for `save()`, shouldn't more than 10 seconds.
2. Will I face data inconsistency problem and how can I overcome it? Consider the following case

   - `onPause` triggered. A thread is launched to perform `save`
   - `onResume` triggered. Loader is launched, to perform `load`
   - Since, previous thread from `onPause` is still not completing `save` operation, `load` from `onResume` might read old data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After several experiments, here's my observation on

### JobScheduler

1. Instead of using `JobScheduler`, we should use `android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService`. Underlying, it will use `JobScheduler` in Android O, and `startService` prior to Android O.
2. Depending on OS. The job will not start immediately in Android O. It may **delay as much as 5 minutes**, before the job start. This is the expected behavior of `JobScheduler`. It decides when to run the job, depending on resource availability.
3. The job can run quite a long period. I did an extreme case by letting the job runs for 10 minutes. No problem unless you kill the app explicitly. (Close the app by using recent task list)

### IntentService

1. It runs immediately.
2. The job can run quite a long period. I did an extreme case by letting the job runs for 10 minutes. No problem unless you kill the app explicitly. (Close the app by using recent task list)

Even though Google advises us to use `JobScheduler`

> Note: If your app targets Android 5.0 (API level 21) or later, it's
>   recommended that you use the JobScheduler to execute background
>   services.

For my case, I need to

1. My task will execute for at most 2 minutes.
2. I need to run the task immediately after the app quits. I don't want it to be delayed.

That's why I choose to use `IntentService`.