# Calling a method 60 seconds after Activity/App goes background

Tags: java, android

I want to clear the clipboard after 60 seconds of putting a text onto the Android clipboard.

I tried the handler postDelayed below. Problem is when the activity is killed or the app goes to background (home button clicked), this function does not execute. How can I make sure to call the function when app is in background?

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           //Clear clipboard
        }
    }, 60000);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute background task when Android app is closed / set to background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39507506/how-to-execute-background-task-when-android-app-is-closed-set-to-background)

Comment: @PacoAbato thanks for pointing in right direction. I found google had a service firebase jobdispatcher (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android).

Comment: @hellomtyj your use case is very simple and could be easily done through a 'Service` as I pointed out in my answer. Otherwise, if you prefer a job handling library, I've updated my answer with the one I strongly suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your Activity doesn't persist after the app is killed, you must go for a Service class. There're some circumstances where it may also be killed, but in a normal basis it will persist in most cases (otherwise check foreground services).

This approach should work:

**Java**

```
public class TestClipboardServiceActivity extends Activity {
    @Override protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startService(new Intent(this, MyClipboardService.class));

        // Forced the app to be destroyed intentionally.
        finish();
    }
}

/**
 * Clipboard Service. It will clear the clipboard after 60 seconds.
 */
public class MyClipboardService extends Service {

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        MyClipboardService getService() {
            return MyClipboardService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("MyClipboardService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);

        // Remember, this is executed in the main thread.
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                clearClipboard();
            }
        }, 6000);

        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    /**
     * Clears the clipboard.
     */
    private void clearClipboard() {
        ClipboardManager myClipboard =
            (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        if (myClipboard != null) {
            myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(ClipData.newPlainText(null, "");
        }
    }
}
```

**Kotlin**

```
class TestClipboardServiceActivity : Activity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    startService(Intent(this, MyClipboardService::class.java))

    // Forced the app to be destroyed intentionally.
    finish()
  }
}

/**
 * Clipboard Service. It will clear the clipboard after 60 seconds.
 */
class MyClipboardService : Service() {

  private val mBinder = LocalBinder()

  inner class LocalBinder : Binder() {
    internal val service: MyClipboardService
      get() = this@MyClipboardService
  }

  override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    Log.i("MyClipboardService", "Received start id $startId: $intent")

    // Remember, this is executed in the main thread.
    Handler().postDelayed(this::clearClipboard, 60000)

    return START_STICKY
  }

  override fun onBind(intent: Intent) = mBinder

  /**
   * Clears the clipboard.
   */
  private fun clearClipboard() {
    val myClipboard = getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
    myClipboard.primaryClip = ClipData.newPlainText(null, "")
  }
}
```

On the other hand, if you prefer to use a custom library to handle jobs, I'll strongly suggest [android-job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) from Evernote. It internally even uses the recent `WorkManager` class and the library contains several scheduling variants, apart from compatibility for many Android API and the lack of Google Play Services library. In your case you could take a look at the [setExact(long exactInMs)](https://evernote.github.io/android-job/javadoc/com/evernote/android/job/JobRequest.Builder.html#setExact-long-) method, providing an offset when the job should run from when the job was scheduled.

Comment: The question is specifically tagged with Java. Why the answer is using kotlin?

Comment: @ישו אוהב אות okey you're right, I've updated the answer with the Java version first, thanks!

Comment: Great! Thanks for the effort!